# How do I get rid of HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL header in squid 3?

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to configure an anonymous proxy using squid.

I've set

```
forwarded_for delete
via delete
```

but Squid 3 still adds an other header to the web requests that go through it:

```
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = max-age=259200
```

I've tried

```
cache_control delete
```

but that doesn't work.

How do I get rid of squid's cache_control header?

I don't want for it to interfere with the actual web requests that contain cache-control header; But I want for it not to attach its own header

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the header with `request_header_access Cache-Control deny all`

But as Serge commented, it's not a good idea. Besides, HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL header is not a proxy header. It's sent by all browsers according to HTTP 1.1 RFC2616, so it's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `Cache-Control` header is a bad idea.

The many sites functionality relies on expected dynamic content delivery. If you filter out this header from the response then your browser will not show you web-pages properly as it will cache everything and after the first request to some page it will show you the same content next time, while if you would request it from the server the content were different.